# Upper and lower derivatives at local minimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

I've come across an exercise in Royden & Fitzpatrick that's got me a bit confused.

It claims that if $c$ is the local minimizer for $f$ in $(a,b)$, then 
$$\underline{D} f(c) \leq 0 \leq \overline{D} f(c).$$

Here $\overline{D}f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left[\sup\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right]$ is the upper derivative, and $\underline{D}f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left[\inf\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right]$ is the lower derivative of f.

Since $c$ is the local minimizer, for a small neighborhood around $c$, $f(c+t)-f(c)>0$ for any $t\in(0,h]$, so I do not see how I can ever get the lower derivative to be negative. No matter what value $t$ takes, it seems that $\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}>0$.

Comment: Are you sure the exercise is about upper and lower derivates and not about the four Dini derivatives (right/left as well as upper and lower)? I've never seen anyone use the notation $D^+$ for an "upper."  My edition of Royden (without the Fitz) does not call them "Dini derivatives" and also has a bad typo in the definition that I hope got corrected for your edition.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: I changed the notation slightly to put it latec, technically the upper has a line above the D, and the lower a line below the D. I have not come across the Dini derivatives just yet.

Comment: So do you mean "\underline{D} f(c) \leq 0 \leq \overline{D} f(c)"  which converts to this when I put dollar signs around it: $$\underline{D} f(c) \leq 0 \leq \overline{D} f(c)?$$

Comment: Clearer now I think.  Consider that $f(c+t)-f(c)\geq 0$ for all small $t>0$.  So the limsup of the values $t^{-1}(f(c+t)-f(c))$ cannot be negative. [This is true just by considering what is happening on the right--its a limsup so, since there are always *some* nonnegative values for the ratio, the limsup cannot be negative.]  On the other hand  $f(c-t)-f(c)\geq 0$ for $t>0$.  So the liminf of the values $t^{-1}(f(c-t)-f(c))$ cannot be positive.  Unless I have messed up the inequalities, this is what you are after.  For your last sentence: remember "yes" if $t>0$ but "no" if $t<0$.

Comment: why we will consider just what is happening on the right?@B.S.Thomson